# SQLite Multiple Subqueries Logic

Tags: sql, sqlite

The problem is asking for one to write a query to find the names (first_name, last_name) of the employees who have a manager who works for a department based in the United States. Here is a link to the problem, to see the tables, https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite-exercises/sqlite-subquery-exercise-3.php.

For the subquery, I did a left join on the location id between the department and location tables then I selected 'US' for the country_id, and returned the manager_id

For the outer query, I chose the Employee table, selected manager_ids from sub-query list.

```
    SELECT first_name, last_name
    FROM Employees
    WHERE manager_id IN (SELECT manager_id
        FROM Departments d LEFT JOIN Locations l ON d.location_id = l.location_id
        WHERE country_id = 'US')
    ORDER BY first_name;
```

With my code, I do not get the correct answer, the same results as the result-set/output shown on the website.
There are three subqueries in total in the correct answer. I do not understand what the purpose of including the subquery involving the employees table (outermost subquery). I understand that is where I messed up but don't understand why.

```
    SELECT first_name, last_name 
    FROM employees 
    WHERE manager_id IN 
       (SELECT employee_id 
        FROM employees 
        WHERE department_id IN 
           (SELECT department_id 
            FROM departments 
            WHERE location_id IN 
                (SELECT location_id 
                 FROM locations 
                 WHERE country_id='US')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join all the tables:

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name
from employees e 
inner join employees m on m.employee_id = e.manager_id 
inner join departments d on d.department_id = m.department_id
inner join locations l on l.location_id = d.location_id
where l.country_id='US'
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Why do you need to two employees tables though? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: This is a self join because the column manager_id references the column employee_id inside the table employees it self.